# file conversion using beanIO

Tags: java, filewriter, bean-io

I am converting csv file to other .xx file using BeanIO.
my question is if I have csv file like

```
  abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno

  pqr,stu,vwx,yzi,sdp
```

my .xx file  I want is to remove ,(comma) and put '$' instead

```
  abc$def$ghi$jkl$mno

  pqr$stu$vwx$yzi$sdp
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify the delimiter for your file like this:

```
<stream name="mydata" format="csv">
    <parser>
        <property name="delimiter" value="$" />
    </parser>
    ...
</stream>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using beanIO a must? You can simple use BufferedReader and Writer to do the task.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
List<String> newLines = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String newline = line.replace(',', '$');
    newLines.add(newline);
}
br.close();

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(csvFile));
for (int i = 0; i < newLines.size(); i++) {
    bw.write(newLines.get(i));
    bw.newLine();
}
bw.close();
```

Using beanIO suppose to have a config maybe xml or annotation to map a batch of properties to your Java entity/class, and perform business logic afterwards, but not replacing any character.

To replace character, there are others library such as POI, but native component such as Scanner already can done that for you.

For you information, java provides:
FileOutputStream, FileWriter, PrintWriter, OutputStreamWriter, BufferedWriter for I/O manipulation.